# Что неправильно в этом коде?

Tags: sql-server, sql

```
use exam007
SELECT *
from EXAM_MARKS
where STUDENT_ID=
(select STUDENT_ID
from STUDENT
where SURNAME='петров');
```

Answer (score 2):

Возможно, правильнее было бы написать:

```
use exam007
SELECT * from EXAM_MARKS where STUDENT_ID in (
    select STUDENT_ID from STUDENT where SURNAME='петров'
);
```

Comment: так тоже не получается.У меня Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: А что выдает ?

    select STUDENT_ID from STUDENT where SURNAME='петров'

Comment: > так тоже не получается.У меня Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2

А какую ошибку-то выдает? MSSQL обычно не секретничает.

Comment: Сейчас нет ошибки и нету никакого результата, просто имя всех колонках в `EXAM_MARKS`.

Comment: Скорее всего просто ничего не находит

Comment: Ну это значит, что он не нашел оценки студента у которого `SURNAME= 'петров'`. Видимо, проблема в самих данных.

Comment: Получилось. Спасибо вам.

Comment: gurgen примите хоть раз правильный ответ

Comment: Единственное я бы написал нестрогое условие, хотя бы на время тестирования:
where SURNAME like '%петр%'

Answer (score 0):

```
use exam007
SELECT EXAM_MARKS.* from EXAM_MARKS, STUDENT where STUDENT.STUDENT_ID = EXAM_MARKS.STUDENT_ID and STUDENT.SURNAME='петров'
```

Может так?) Не бейте - MSSQL знаю плохо, все таки надеюсь, что такой синтаксис там есть, как в MySql:)

Comment: Так тоже:)

Answer (score 0):

Ну попробуйте так:

```
use exam007
SELECT e.* from EXAM_MARKS e
join STUDENT s on e.STUDENT_ID=s.STUDENT_ID and s.SURNAME='петров'
```

может, загвоздка еще вот в этом условии - `s.SURNAME='петров'`, попробуйте использовать оператор `like`.

Answer (score 0):

Проверь так с различными импровизациями на тему `'%петр%'`, `'%етр%'`:

```
 use exam007
    SELECT e.*
    from EXAM_MARKS e
    inner join STUDENT s on e.STUDENT_ID = s.STUDENT_ID
    WHERE 
         s.SURNAME like '%петров%'
```

Если пусто, проверь, что

```
SELECT STUDENT_ID
FROM STUDENT s
WHERE 
     s.SURNAME like '%петров%'
```

не даёт `null` в `STUDENT_ID`.

Answer (score 0):

А мне кажется, всё же "петров" нужно с большой буквы написать или таки условие сделать таким:

```
upper(s.SURNAME)=upper('петров')
```

Но может понадобиться индекс, если предиакты такого вида будут постоянно.

Answer (score -1):

точки с запятой не хватает после `use exam007`?

Comment: В случае с MS SQL это не обязательно

Comment: Тогда не вижу никаких иных проблем.